# ERROR: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables

Tags: metadata, amazon-redshift, pg

Trying to get metadata on tables with the following query:

```
SET SEARCH_PATH to '$user', 'public', 'myschema';
select schemaname,tablename, col, typ, nn, row_number()
OVER(PARTITION BY col, typ, nn) As row
from 
(
SELECT n.nspname::text AS schemaname, c.relname::text AS tablename, 
a.attname::text AS col, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod)::text AS typ, 
format_encoding(a.attencodingtype::integer)::text AS "encoding", 
a.attisdistkey AS "distkey", a.attsortkeyord AS "sortkey", a.attnotnull AS nn
  FROM pg_namespace n, pg_class c, pg_attribute a
  WHERE n.oid = c.relnamespace AND c.oid = a.attrelid AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped AND pg_table_is_visible(c.oid)
  ORDER BY n.nspname, c.relname, a.attnum
) tt
where schemaname = 'myschema' and tablename like 'tbl\\_%';
```

But I'm getting the error: `ERROR: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.`

I had been trying using the info schema views but found that it's best to use the redshift specific `pg_...` views instead to avoid these types of error, yet they are still happening.

How can I run this query without getting those errors?

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the built-in view [`svv_table_info`](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/tree/master/src/AdminViews) to get this information.

You may also be interested in the "[Admin Views](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/tree/master/src/AdminViews)" we have published on GitHub in our Utils.